# How rails form instance works?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have these two methods, show and create.

```
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment.article_id = @article.id
end

def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.article_id = params[:article_id]
    @comment.save
    redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
end
```

Show method displays my comment form.

In the show method why do we create a new instance of `Comment` and also associate the comment 
instance to an article id.

Create method actually handles the submission of form.

In the create method, again i am creating a new comment object and again associating the comment's article_id.

My whole questing is why were repeating these things?. Why do I have associate my comment form with `article_id` when I am displaying it and again I am repeating the steps while submitting the form too.

Comment: You shouldn't have to set `article_id` in create if you render it as a hidden field in comment form. Then it'll be submitted in the form and be set in `Comment.new(comment_params)`

Comment: Try to remove `@comment.article_id = @article.id` from your `show` action and see what happens.

Comment: @Stefan: It gets submitted, I am totally confused on these parts.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Why do we have to set it in show form either way? I am just display a comment form?.

Comment: @Shane so it works without assigning `article_id` (in `show`) and the comment is associated with the correct article afterwards?

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, It works. Here is the article which I am referring. http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i2:-adding-comments

Comment: I would suggest using `@comment = @article.comments.new` instead - directly assigning to an association id is not very 'Rails-y'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you initialize a comment both times is because the user's browser only sees the html form - it doesn't have a concept of a `Comment` - and because each request to a Rails application is independent - nothing is persisted in the application between requests:

When the user requests the `show` page for an `Article`, the request is handled by the application something like this:

1. The controller creates a new `Comment` object (in memory).
2. The `form_for` helpers in the view build a form from that `Comment`.
3. The html for the `show` page is sent to the user's browser.

At this point the application has done everything it needs to serve this request, so the temporary `Comment` object is deleted.

When the user submits the form, the values that were entered are sent to the application in the `comment_params` and the application handles this request like this:

1. The controller creates a new `Comment` object (again in memory), but initializes it with the data that the user sent through in `comment_params`.
2. The controller saves the `Comment` - this stores the `Comment` in the database so it can be loaded later.
3. The controller redirects back to the `show` page.

Saving to the database is the main way that the application can persist things between requests - objects in memory only exist while the request is being processed.

Answer (score 2):

This repetition could be avoided if you keep those resources nested and build the form as:

```
<%= form_for(@article, @article.comments.build) do |f| %>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I am trying to understand why are we repeating and also what path does this form_for of yours generate?

Comment: Associating in the show action what you wrote is not required. My form would generate `/articles/:article_id/comments` path

Comment: @Shane: He's assuming you have nested resources and the proper model associations, otherwise that code is not going to work.

Comment: @Serg right! And as per conventions, that is what is expected while adding comments! :)

Comment: @SiriusROR: This is my form_for, <%= form_for [@article, @comment] do |f| %>. I see it too generating the same path as u mentioned.

Comment: Great! Then you can pass article_id in hidden field to avoid the reassignment :)

Comment: @SiriusROR: I am following this article, my whole question is why are they following like that. I am trying to understand the rails convention way. http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i2:-adding-comments

Comment: I saw the article. It doesn't seem to follow all the conventions. We never explicitly assign associated objects as `@comment.article_id = article.id` as per conventions. Instead we use `article.comments.build`. If you want to understand the proper rails conventions then refer [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)